# delete file from jetty server using java 7

Tags: java, jetty, java-7

I am working on web application which is running on jetty server.
In this application I am uploading and image and use this image in my jsp page.
Now when I want to delete it using

```
Files.delete(File Path)
```

It gives me error

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: "File Path": The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Comment: Can you post where else you are using that file?

Answer (score 0):

Close all streams associated with that file before you attempt to delete it. Consider also the use of [try-with-resources](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-7-new-try-resources) with the file you're uploading to.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Jetty is locking static files it serves via default servlet. It is a common issue.  It has something to do with caching. See wiki:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deal_with_Locked_Windows_Files

You need to switch `useFileMappedBuffer` to false.